# what mean error :AttributeError: lower not found in classification project?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, tfidfvectorizer, smote

I have a python that is written using jupyter notebook and  deal with classification topics project that have in the an unbalanced dataset, for this i used **SMOTE** but when I tried to split the dataset and create a pipeline to use machine learning model the system crash and display the below error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-17-7ae8518f1892> in <module>
     15                 ('clf',MultinomialNB()), # model classifier
     16             ])
---> 17 nb.fit(x_train,y_train)

f:\AIenv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y,
**fit_params)
    328         """
    329         fit_params_steps = self._check_fit_params(**fit_params)
--> 330         Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    331         with _print_elapsed_time('Pipeline',
    332                                  self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):

f:\AIenv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y,
**fit_params_steps)
    294                 message_clsname='Pipeline',
    295                 message=self._log_message(step_idx),
--> 296                 **fit_params_steps[name])
    297             # Replace the transformer of the step with the fitted
    298             # transformer. This is necessary when loading the transformer

f:\AIenv\lib\site-packages\joblib\memory.py in __call__(self, *args,
**kwargs)
    353 
    354     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 355         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    356 
    357     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):

f:\AIenv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in
_fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    738     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    739         if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 740             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    741         else:
    742             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

f:\AIenv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)    1197     1198         vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents,
-> 1199                                           self.fixed_vocabulary_)    1200     1201         if self.binary:

f:\AIenv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in
_count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab)    1108         for doc in raw_documents:    1109             feature_counter = {}
-> 1110             for feature in analyze(doc):    1111                 try:    1112                     feature_idx = vocabulary[feature]

f:\AIenv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in
_analyze(doc, analyzer, tokenizer, ngrams, preprocessor, decoder, stop_words)
    102     else:
    103         if preprocessor is not None:
--> 104             doc = preprocessor(doc)
    105         if tokenizer is not None:
    106             doc = tokenizer(doc)

f:\AIenv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in
_preprocess(doc, accent_function, lower)
     67     """
     68     if lower:
---> 69         doc = doc.lower()
     70     if accent_function is not None:
     71         doc = accent_function(doc)

f:\AIenv\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    685             return self.getnnz()
    686         else:
--> 687             raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
    688 
    689     def transpose(self, axes=None, copy=False):

AttributeError: lower not found
```

## code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE# for inbalance dataset
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer,TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

df = pd.read_csv("data/emotion_dataset_raw.csv")
df["clean_text"] = df["Text"].apply(clean_text)
vectorizer =TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2))
vect_df =vectorizer.fit_transform(df["clean_text"])
oversample = SMOTE(random_state = 42)
x_smote,y_smote = oversample.fit_resample(vect_df, df["Emotion"])
print("shape x before SMOTE: {}".format(vect_df.shape))
print("shape x after SMOTE: {}".format(x_smote.shape))
print("balance of targets feild %")
y_smote.value_counts(normalize = True)*100

# the result of the code above :
#shape x before SMOTE: (34792, 209330)
#shape x after SMOTE: (88360, 209330)

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x_smote,y_smote,test_size = 0.2,random_state =42)

#Naiive Bayes Classifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
  
nb = Pipeline([
                ('vect',CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2))),
                ('tfidf',TfidfTransformer()),
                ('clf',MultinomialNB()), # model classifier 
            ])
nb.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

where is the error in my code and what it mean ???

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the `TfidfTransformer` is good enough to generate text embeddings. You can drop the `CountVectorizer` and run the code again. I should work!

```
pipe = Pipeline(
[
    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
    ('sampler', RandomOverSampler(sampling_strategy='not majority', random_state=7)),
    ('model', XGBClassifier())
]
)

pipe.fit(data['features'], data['labels'])
```